# php _GET parameter passed through URL trouble, any length or size restriction on the url?

Tags: php, mysql, url, get

I am moving my site to a new cPanel linux server, here is the comparison of the new and old server:

New Server:
php version:5.6.25 (Zend: 2.6.0)
Database:   MySQL 5.5.52-cll
Server OS:  Linux 2.6.18-502.el5.lve0.8.85

Old server:(as far as I can remember)
php version:5.2.36 
Database:   MySQL 5.3.1

Most codes are running just fine. But one file just let me pull out my hair. Here is the trick:

The function is for updating the product data through URL after action is set, let say I hit the "update" button after input the form area.

For some products having less attributes the code output shorter URL like the following, the function works perfectly updating the database:

http://www.domainname.com/demo/admin/stock.php?quantity0=1&product_id=188&cPath=81&quantity1=5&product_id=188&cPath=81&quantity2=3&product_id=188&cPath=81&quantity3=0&product_id=188&cPath=81&quantity4=0&product_id=188&cPath=81&quantity5=0&product_id=188&cPath=81&quantity6=0&product_id=188&cPath=81&quantity7=0&product_id=188&cPath=81&quantity8=0&product_id=188&cPath=81&quantity9=0&product_id=188&cPath=81&quantity10=0&product_id=188&cPath=81&quantity11=0&product_id=188&cPath=81&quantity12=0&product_id=188&cPath=81&quantity13=0&product_id=188&cPath=81&quantity14=0&product_id=188&cPath=81&quantity15=0&product_id=188&cPath=81&quantity16=0&product_id=188&cPath=81&quantity17=0&product_id=188&cPath=81&quantity18=0&product_id=188&cPath=81&quantity19=0&product_id=188&cPath=81&quantity20=0&product_id=188&cPath=81&quantity21=0&product_id=188&cPath=81&quantity22=0&product_id=188&cPath=81&quantity23=0&product_id=188&cPath=81&action=Update

BUT:

For some products having more attributes the code output longer URL like the following, the function didn't work at all:

http://www.domainname.com/demo/admin/stock.php?quantity0=0&product_id=413&cPath=83&quantity1=0&product_id=413&cPath=83&quantity2=0&product_id=413&cPath=83&quantity3=0&product_id=413&cPath=83&quantity4=0&product_id=413&cPath=83&quantity5=2&product_id=413&cPath=83&quantity6=0&product_id=413&cPath=83&quantity7=0&product_id=413&cPath=83&quantity8=0&product_id=413&cPath=83&quantity9=0&product_id=413&cPath=83&quantity10=0&product_id=413&cPath=83&quantity11=0&product_id=413&cPath=83&quantity12=0&product_id=413&cPath=83&quantity13=0&product_id=413&cPath=83&quantity14=1&product_id=413&cPath=83&quantity15=1&product_id=413&cPath=83&quantity16=0&product_id=413&cPath=83&quantity17=0&product_id=413&cPath=83&quantity18=0&product_id=413&cPath=83&quantity19=0&product_id=413&cPath=83&quantity20=1&product_id=413&cPath=83&quantity21=0&product_id=413&cPath=83&quantity22=0&product_id=413&cPath=83&quantity23=0&product_id=413&cPath=83&quantity24=1&product_id=413&cPath=83&quantity25=1&product_id=413&cPath=83&quantity26=2&product_id=413&cPath=83&quantity27=2&product_id=413&cPath=83&quantity28=3&product_id=413&cPath=83&quantity29=1&product_id=413&cPath=83&quantity30=1&product_id=413&cPath=83&quantity31=1&product_id=413&cPath=83&quantity32=0&product_id=413&cPath=83&quantity33=1&product_id=413&cPath=83&quantity34=1&product_id=413&cPath=83&quantity35=1&product_id=413&cPath=83&quantity36=1&product_id=413&cPath=83&quantity37=1&product_id=413&cPath=83&quantity38=1&product_id=413&cPath=83&quantity39=0&product_id=413&cPath=83&action=Update

My thinking is there might be some setting with php.ini/apache/mysql, or even the browers that restricts the length of the URL, or something else I don't even know about.

Any idea will be appreciated.

Seahorse

---

Problem solved. It is the setting of directive "suhosin.get.max_vars" too small to pass too many parameters in the URL. Double the value from 200 to 400 it works back to normal. – Seahorse Nov 7 at 2:36

Comment: How are we supposed to magically know this? Check your server logs, post the code that handles this query.

Comment: the code is over 300 lines, and contains many functions included from other files, I do not think it is possible to post the code. But the two URL I post were generated from the same code, ONE worked but THE OTHER did not, that is why I shrank the questions to the configuration of PHP/APACHE/SQL/BROWSER...my hosting just adjusted the php.ini with "suhosin.get.max_value_length=100000" but that did not solve the problem. Thanks anyways for reading my question.

Answer (score 2):

The de facto limit is 2000 characters. That being said, is it possible to change it? Yes. Should you change it? No, because even if you set a higher limit, some of the most popular web browsers have limitations of their own, making your application less accessible.

Since what you are doing is an update, I would recommend you to use a POST request instead of a GET, and then simply getting the attributes from the request using the global variable $_POST.

Comment: Hi Diegowc, thanks for your answer. What is you referred about the 2000 characters limit? did you mean browsers of php rules or server setting? Please give more detailed instruction to change that limit. I do not want to change the codes as they seem working still fine other than this issue. Thanks.

Comment: I did use $_POST for the ['quantity'] which is input into the form. the other two ['product_id'] & ['cPath'] need to be passed back and forth by $_GET from other application. I am thinking this is a back end system which is basically only used by limited users, so I won't worry too much about the browser issue, as long as it works out. I use the same file with the previous server for more than 10 years without any problem, from PHP 4 unitl PHP 5.2.. and until I moved the site to the new server since the Oct 7,2016.

Comment: You can try to add the line LimitRequestLine 100000 to your apache2.conf and restart apache. That might do the trick

Comment: I am waiting for the hosting to do that for me. I am not good at commands, is it possible to update that directive in

Comment: Is it possible to update that directive in .htaccess? If yes can anyone tell me how to write the code? Thanks.

Comment: The issue here is that from what I researched there are a bunch of points where you might have to change it... I would give the apache2.conf a try and if that works, awesome! If not, you are gonna run into less trouble if you could change that GET for a POST request. Good luck Seahorse

Comment: Thanks diegowc. I am in a share hosting and don't have control on httpd.conf or apache2.conf, actually I do not know how to do it. I just sent in a request to my hosting to see if they can update "LimitRequestLine" for me. If it is not working  eventually, I will work on the code. But still very curious why it doesn't work. Thanks again anyway.

Comment: Problem solved. It is the setting of directive "suhosin.get.max_vars" too small to pass too many parameters in the URL. Double the value from 200 to 400 it works back to normal.

Comment: You should edit your question reflecting the answer you found, maybe someone will find it useful. Congrats!

Comment: how to edit the question to let readers know the problem has been solved?

Comment: You should see an "edit" button at the bottom of your post. I would add a section called Edit where you explain how you fixed the issue, so the next person to come around can just look there.